# How do you resolve the error "E: Unmet dependencies."?

Tags: installation, apt, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I did try `apt-get -f install` but that didn't work either.

The problem appeared after installing a modified version of [libapache2-mod-wsgi](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libapache2-mod-wsgi).

I modified the package dependencies because, as you can see from the package details link, it depends on python 3. A version of python is required but not version 3 necessarily and I didn't want to install version 3. There's [bug #672901](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-wsgi/+bug/672901) that describes the problem.

So, modifying the package dependencies worked but now that I try to install another package I get the error above. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: How did you modify the dependencies?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.